# Two different submit buttons on the same line

Tags: html, forms, django-forms

I have two submit buttons part of two different forms. They are being displayed on two different lines. Is it possible to have them, side by side on a single line.

```
<form action="" method="POST">
        <input type="submit" name = "" value="OK" >
                    </form> 
<form action="" method="POST">
        <input type="submit" name = "" value="Cancel" >
                    </form>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
<div style="width:400px;">
    <div style="float: left; width: 130px"> 
        <form id="thisone" action="post_nrs_users.asp" method="post">
            <input type="submit" name = "" value="OK" >
        </form>
    </div>
    <div style="float: right; width: 225px"> 
        <form id="thistoo" action="post_nrs_users.asp" method="post">
            <input type="submit" name = "" value="Cancel" >
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please, explain your answer in words.

Comment: set your style up like this `<div style="float: left; padding-left: 50px">` to have control over the position of the buttons.

Answer (score 17):

The other way is to change the css properties for the form tags:

```
form { display: inline; }
```

Example: http://jsbin.com/omene3/2/edit

Comment: This is the best and fastest solution for me.

Comment: this the best and the faster solution

Answer (score 4):

Sure. Use the following CSS:

```
form { float: left; }
```

or

```
input { float: left; }
```